# how to send long text with send_keys using selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, google-chrome

I want to send a text that contains more than 4000 characters, and when I do that the browser

crushs and keep opening new tabs (idk why), but when I try to send only 600 characters it works fine.

```
browser.get('website')
search = browser.find_element_by_id("text-area")
search.clear()
#browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', search, data)
search.send_keys(data[0:600])
browser.find_element_by_id("btn").click()
```

"data" is the variable containing the text (all good with it)

I tried the script in comment and it does send all of the text, but when the browser click on the button .

it reads the old text (default one)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time!!

Comment: please add the website information

Comment: @PDHide added, please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home')
search = browser.find_element_by_id("text-area")
search.clear()
search.click()

#browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', search, data)
data = "sadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadassadas"

search.send_keys(data[0:2000])
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.find_element_by_id("btn").click()

input()
```

just add a sleep before clicking the button , i was not able to see any changes in dom to use explicit wait. but this works

Comment: thanks for your time, i tried copy in clipboard and paste and worked perfectly for me.

Comment: you don't have enough reputation , you can accept the answer if it works for you by clicking the tick sign